# Как работает цикл while в данном примере?

Tags: java, while

```
public class RevereseNum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, reverse = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter an integer to reverse");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();

        while (n != 0) {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse of the number is " + reverse);
```

Данный код запрашивает ввод числа в консоль, а после переворачивает цифры в обратном порядке, но я не пойму как это происходит? Т.е. как число переворачивается с помощью данного цикла? Цикл разве не бесконечный в данному случае?

Comment: Дебажить пробовали? :)

Comment: Возьмите листок бумаги, карандаш и какое-нибудь не очень длинное число. Выполните код цикла на бумаге, сообщите о результатах.

Answer (score 5):

Возьмем число на вводе `n=12345` и пронумеруем строки в цикле:

```
while (n != 0) {                    //1
        reverse = reverse * 10;     //2  
        reverse = reverse + n % 10; //3 
        n = n / 10;
    }
```

Итак, на первой итерации:

```
reverse = 0 * 10;
reverse = 0 + 12345 % 10; // = 0+5=5
n = 12345 / 10;           // = 1234,5, но поскольку n - integer, приводится к 1234
//reverse = 5; n = 1234;
```

Далее:

```
reverse = 5 * 10;         // = 50
reverse = 50 + 1234 % 10; // = 50+4 = 54
n = 1234 / 10;            // = 123
// reverse = 54; n = 123;
```

Итого: на каждой итерации код смещает цифры в `reverse` на разряд влево, добавляет в младший разряд цифру младшего разряда из `n`, и смещает цифры в `n` вправо, удаляя младший разряд.

Comment: Слабо разжевано, жуйте еще.

Comment: @Igor да куда уж еще, скоро думать разучатся :)